# How to have a One Common ProgressBar in Android Project

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm currently trying to sort out a way to have a single Common `ProgressBar` to everywhere(`Activity`/`Fragment`) I need in my Android Project. The methods I tried did not promise me good results. Please help me to find a better solution. An example with code for android java is more than welcome.

This is my Custom ProgressBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fl_common_probar"
android:elevation="40dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<View
    android:id="@+id/background_dim_pro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@color/textTitleW"
    android:elevation="50dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_container_pro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:elevation="60dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_test"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_loading" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_circle_pro"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:indeterminateDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a Java class Seperately for Progress Dialog
public class ProgressDialog {

private Dialog dialog;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

public ProgressDialog(Context context) {
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
        dialog.getWindow()
                .setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
    progressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(randomColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            new Handler().postDelayed(this, 300);
        }
    }, 0);

}

public void showDialog() {
    if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.show();
}

public void hideDialog() {
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.cancel();
}}

//Now you can use it in anywhere in you activity/fragment
```

Activity:

```
public class ShowProgressBar extends AppCompatActivity{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_web_pages);

 progressDialog= new ProgressDialog (ShowProgressBar.this);

 }



//Use these methods in your code where you want to show the progress dialog or hide the dialog.
// showing animated dialog
public void showDialog(){
    progressDialog.showDialog();
}

// hide animated dialog
public void hideDialog(){
    progressDialog.hideDialog();
}
```

Comment: thank you Zoe for the responce, already i have a custom ProgressBar with a definite layout of its own. so im wondering how  can i make it a common layout and call in places which i need it to be called, instead of putting that custom progress bar in every xml that i need the progress bar to showup. :) :)

Comment: I have edited my answer.Please check this @PixxuWaku.

Comment: thank you for the effort, but not what i really intended.

Comment: Oh, I got it. And yeah this is not what you need after I looked your code. Before this, you didn't post your code right?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below approach.

1.) Create a `layout xml` file (`dialog_progress.xml`) with the below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2.) Create `AppUtil Java class` and create a static method as below.

```
public class AppUtil {

    // progress bar handling
    public static Dialog showProgress(Activity activity) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(0));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress);
        ProgressBar progressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

3.) When you need to show a `ProgressBar` in an `Activity`/`Fragment` do as below.

```
Dialog dialog = AppUtil.showProgress(MainActivity.this);
```

When you need to `dissmiss` the `progressBar`

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

That's it. Try and let me know your feedback.
Thank you.

Comment: actually what i need is the progressbar to be available as a common util. not to include it in a dialog and show  the dialog. The main reason why i dont need it in a dialog is i dont need that shadow from the dialog when it appears on the screen.

Comment: If you need to hide that shadow you can do it. Update `showProgress(Activity activity)` method as below.
`// progress bar handling
    public static Dialog showProgress(Activity activity) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(0));
        dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        ...
        return dialog;
    }`

Comment: Use this code snip to remove the dialog shadow.
`dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);`

Comment: i tried your solution... but i dont even get the progress bar with the dialog visible in my page..